# Should [tag:sleep] and [tag:suspend] combine?

Tags: discussion, tags

[sleep](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep) and [suspend](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspend) appear to cover identical scope. The former might sometimes include [hibernate](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hibernate), but that is currently handled by a separate tag. Would it make sense to combine the first two? All three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sleep has only 6 questions and suspend has 30, and sleep is always a suspend, I have merged them. While hibernation is also suspension, I don't believe elementary ever calls it that.

Comment: [tag:hibernate] was more that users have used that path before (and meant [tag:sleep]/suspend) so it's likely a good alias